# Enum Size *in practice*

Tags: c++

For C++ prior 2011, the standard says that enums can be any size, from byte to long long.  But in practice it seems most compilers make them ints, 4 bytes.

So, *in practice* do any vaguely current compilers not make them ints?

And I seem to need to clarify that I am not doing anything weird, like enums > 2^31.  Just simple enums.  And on 32 or 64 bit systems, my software will not run on 16 bits!

Comment: `int` isn't necessarily 4 bytes.

Comment: `enum /*class*/ MyEnum : unsigned char { ... };`. In C99 compiler, one of my client reported an error which boiled down to an unrelated module assuming size of enum = sizeof UINT32.

Comment: ... and a byte isn't necessarily 8 bits.

Comment: The default type is guaranteed sufficient for the specified values. If you want a particular underlying type then just specify it. E.g. `enum Foos : long { bah = 42 };`

Answer (score 9):

Let's see it on any modern compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

enum MySmallSmall {
  SmallValue = 0,
};

enum MyLongLong {
  LongValue = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "sizeof MySmallSmall is " << sizeof(MySmallSmall) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sizeof MyLongLong is " << sizeof(MyLongLong) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

clang and g++ output:

> sizeof MySmallSmall is 4
>
> sizeof MyLongLong is 8

But for MS Visual Studio both results are 4 (I've checked it using this site http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual not sure what compiler version is here)

So you can't rely on sizeof of any enum.

Comment: I don't see how this answer adds anything. It was already stated in the question that the underlying type is implementation-defined.

Comment: Also MSVC is wrong here. The max value of `long long` cannot fit into `int`, so it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper the question was "So, in practice do any vaguely current compilers not make them ints?"... There is only one way to answer  on practice question, check it.
And you are correct that msvc doesn't follow the standard. But this is a life and developers have to adopt to it.

Comment: I just told you why the question premise and MSVC are wrong.

Comment: As I clarified in the question, it is the normal cases that I was concerned about.  Obviously enums >2^31 are going to be a bit dubious.

Comment: @aberglas why do you concern about it? Probably you shoud redesign/revise your approach if you need to know sizeof of enums.

Answer (score 7):

If an `enum` was always an `int`, then the following would be unsafe:

```
enum oops {
    foo = 32767,
    bar, /*what am I?*/
};
```

This is because an `int` can be as small as 16 bits (and that is still surprisingly common). On a system with a 32 bit `int`, you could set `foo = 2147483647` and your compiler most certainly *wouldn't* pick an `int` as the underlying type.

So the clever C++ bods specify that the underlying `enum` integral type must be capable of representing the values given, and a compiler is free to pick one that's appropriate. Given that `int` is often considered as the machine's native type, it's often a sensible choice.

If you want to know the underlying type of an `enum`, then [std::underlying_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) provides this.

Comment: `and your compiler most certainly wouldn't pick an int as the underlying type.` MSVC does pick `int` to represent `long long`, resulting in truncation. It *does* give a warning but I personally believe it should be a hard error.